# where to find the laravel installation folder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have downloaded `Composer-setup.exe` and when I run it, it didn't ask for installation folder but it asked for php.exe location.

the location of `php.exe` in my machine is `c:xampp2\php\php.exe`

The installation finished and when i type `composer` in my cmd i can see the results but where can I find the laravel please?

I read on internet that I should have this image [image]
when the installation complete but I don't know what is the url to check in.

the aparche server is running on port 8082 so i tried localhost:8082/laravel/public but i got error

should I install anything else to have laravel installed?

where can I find laravel?

thanks

Comment: Install composer, like you did, then cd into the directory you want to install laravel in, then run the command found here: http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation

Comment: @joseph4tw before you typed your answer, I typed this on cmd `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` and the cmd is still downloading. i hope i have done a good thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm nor answering what you are up to but I'm suggesting you to use [Laravel Installer](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel) which is more faster than `Composer` installer and very easy but despite of this you need to install `Composer` as you already did. Anyways...

Make sure you have added the `c:xampp2\php` in your system's `path`, It's possible to add this from  `system properties -> environment variable` and you need to just add the path (where your `php.exe` lives) in the `path` by adding a semicolon at last, something this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WANdisco\Subversion;c:xampp2\php;
```

Once you added the path then download `Laravel Installer` from [Laravel website here](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel) and click the download link labeled with `Laravel installer PHAR archive`. keep it in your `htdocs` folder (`xampp2\htdocs`) and rename the downloaded file to `laravel` (remove the `.phar` extension). Once you done everything as described above then install `Laravel` by simply running following command within your `xampp2\htdocs` folder from the `command prompt`, for example:

> 1. Run the command prompt (Dos Shell)
> 2. Goto `xampp2\htdocs` folder
> 3. Then run `php laravel new myApp`

Here `myApp` will be created inside the `xampp2\htdocs` folder and `Laravel` will be installed in a minute. Then just use `cd myApp` from `xampp2\htdocs` folder and you'll be in your `Laravel` installation folder. That's it. Fore more, [read the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel).